# Imagex.exe performance

Tags: windows, disk-image, imagex

I'm using Microsoft's imagex.exe for backup and restore in 2 configurations: A mirror raid of 2 500GB hard drives, and a mirror raid of 2 1TB hard drives. The second configuration is 30% slower even though in both configurations the number of files and their size is about the same.

My question are:

1. What are the parameters that effect the speed of Microsoft's
   imagex.exe in general?
2. Would a 1TB hard drive be slower than 500GB hard drive, even though
   they both contain the same amount of data?

Thank you

Comment: Are they using the same controller? are they both the same speed in terms of interface and RPM? Are you doing this from within Windows or from a boot disc? I suspect a driver could be to blame if that's the case. If you're using the verify switch or compression, try with or without those options. What's the exact syntax you're using to call imagex?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a different configuration: The 1TB is through SATA3 on a recently released motherboard, the 500GB is through SATA2 running on a motherboard from a few years ago. Same RPM. I'm running the simplest commands "imagex /capture" and "imagex /apply". This is done through WinPE.

Comment: My only guess is that imagex takes longer because it's a bigger disk it has to scan, either that or there is some strange driver issue.